# Reusing a select query in multiple stored procedures

Tags: sql, select, database-design, sql-server-2012

I need to retrieve a record from a table in three different workflows. Each of these workflows is calling three different stored procedures due to which I have to write select column1, column2, column3, column4 etc from table 1 in all the three stored procedures.

Is there a way to consolidate this select in all the three stored procedures into one?

I am using SQL Server 2012. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I can think of:

1. Create an additional stored procedure that runs the query, and call this stored procedure from the other three procedures.
2. Create a view that contains the select statement, and select * from this view within the procedures.

Comment: the select query in my all the stored procs is required to join in with the other tables in the respective stored porc ,so i am not sure will that help

Comment: To be honest, if that's the case, I'd personally just stick to Copy & Paste.